# android package

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to android development.

I have a doubt that while creating an android project (using Eclipse) it asks to specify a package name in project properties which is in the form **sample.android** but not single name like **sample**.

What is the reason behind it to follow such naming convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just go through these lines--->For example, if an organization in Canada called MySoft creates a package to deal with fractions, naming the package ca.mysoft.fractions distinguishes the fractions package from another similar package created by another company. If a US company named MySoft also creates a fractions package, but names it us.mysoft.fractions, then the classes in these two packages are defined in a unique and separate namespace.

Answer (score 1):

this is just plain programming convetion.

to avoid conflicts with other company, developer's packages.

check this link.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions